# Closing a webview on url detection

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview in my activity and I need to close it once the final url is being loaded. 
I tried `destroy()` in the custom Client but that wasn't allowed, `finish()` closed the entire app, back key closed the app too. Is there a way to just remove the webview and return to the rest of activity.

```
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);

            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl(myUrl);
       }
      private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.matches(PATTERN)) {
                    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(PATTERN).matcher(url);
                    result = matcher.matches() ? matcher.group(1) : null;
  //                webview.destroy(); //doesn't work as destroy cannot be called from here 
                    return false;
                }
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't call finish() of your remaining Activities, when you calling WebView class. Because if previous Activities was finish() then it will get back to you out of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove webView from parent by:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)webView.getParent();
if(vg != null)
   vg.removeView(webView);
```

Or try just webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);